# Forbid explicit type parameters or constrain union type parameters for more type safety

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The following Typescript code works fine, when the `getValues()` function is invoked without explicit type parameters. However when it is called with explicit type parameters, it can lead to errors (see invocation `getValues<'a' | 'b' | 'c' >(store, 'a', 'b')` below).

```
type Store = Record<string, string>;

function getValues<T extends string>(
    store: Store, ...keys: T[]
): {[P in T]: string} {
    const values = {} as {[P in T]: string};

    keys.forEach((p) => {
        const value = store[p];
        if (value) {
            values[p] = value;
        } else {
            values[p] = 'no value';
        }
    });

    return values;
}


// Usage / requirements:    

const store: Store = {}; // assume it is filled with arbitrary values


// in the following line values1 is inferred to be of type
// {a: string, b: string}, which is the required behavior
const values1 = getValues(store, 'a', 'b');


// the following line does not compile, which is the required behavior
// Argument of type 'b' is not assignable to parameter of type 'a' | 'c'
const values2 = getValues<'a' | 'c'>(store, 'a', 'b');


// in the following line values3 is inferred to be of type
// {a: string, b: string, c: string}, which is NOT the required behavior
// the required behavior would be to forbid this situation, similar to
// how values2 declaration was forbidden by the compiler.
const values3 = getValues<'a' | 'b' | 'c' >(store, 'a', 'b');

// now values3.c can be accessed
// values3.c cannot have a value and will cause an error when used
```

Is there a way to prevent the caller from providing explicit type parameters or any other way to make this code more type-safe without making the return type of the getValues function partial or making its return type's properties optional.

The following ideas come to my mind, for which I don't know whether or how they are possible in Typescript:

Idea 1: prevent explicit type parameters to be provided

Idea 2: remove getValues' value arguments and access the provided type arguments at runtime

Idea 3: enforce all provided type arguments to be used as value arguments also. That is, the declaration of values3 constant above will lead to a compile error.

I am aware that the problem is caused by the unsafe type assertion `as {[P in T]: string}`. I am looking for a way to make this type-safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be more trouble than it's worth; the level of complexity involved in trying to get such guarantees from the type system is unfortunately high, and should be weighed against the likelihood of people manually specifying too-wide type parameters.  Perhaps you can just document the function (`/** hey, let the compiler infer T, thanks **/`) instead of trying to make the compiler enforce this for you.

---

First, there's no way to prevent explicit type parameters from being specified. Even if you could it might not help you much, since type inference could still result in the wider types you are trying to avoid:

```
const aOrB = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";
getValues(store, aOrB); // {a: string, b: string} again
```

You also can't access type parameters at runtime because they, like the rest of the static type system, are [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) upon transpilation to JavaScript.

---

From looking around, I think TS folks have run into this when trying to deal with [computed property keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), which have a similar problem.  The solution proposed (but not implemented in the language, see [microsoft/TypeScript#21030](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030) and linked issues for discussion) seems to be something called `Unionize` in which you'd get `{a: string} | {b: string}` if you didn't know if the key is `"a"` or `"b"`.

---

I think I could imagine using a type like `Unionize` in concert with taking an [programmatic intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) of these types for each key passed in.  That implies you want your generic parameter not to be a union of key types, but a [rest tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) of key types:

```
type UnionizeRecord<K, V> = K extends PropertyKey ? { [P in K]: V } : never;
type Expand<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
type UnionizeRecordTupleKeys<K extends PropertyKey[], V> = Expand<
    { [I in keyof K]: (x: UnionizeRecord<K[I], V>) => void }[number] extends
    ((x: infer R) => void) ? R : never
>;
```

The `UnionizeRecord<K,V>` type is like `Record<K, V>` but produces a union of types, one for each key in `K`.  The `Expand<T>` type just helps with IntelliSense output; it turns an intersection like `{a: string} & {bar: number}` into an equivalent single object type like `{a: string, bar: number}`.  And `UnionizeRecordTupleKeys<K, V>` is, well, ugly.  What it does is walks through each index `I` of the `K` tuple and produces a `UnionizeRecord<K[I], V>`.  It then intersects them together and expands them.  The specifics for how that all works are explained via [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and [inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types).

Your `getValues()` function then looks something like this:

```
function getValues<K extends (number extends K['length'] ? [string] : string[])>(
    store: Store, ...keys: [...K]
): UnionizeRecordTupleKeys<K, string> {
    const values = {} as any; // not worried about impl safety here

    keys.forEach((p) => {
        const value = store[p];
        if (value) {
            values[p] = value;
        } else {
            values[p] = 'no value';
        }
    });

    return values;
}
```

I'm not bothering trying to make the compiler understand that it can assign things to a value of type `UnionizeRecordTupleKeys<K, string>` when `K` is an unspecified generic type parameter, so I used `any` inside the implementation.  The other wrinkle is that I [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) the `K` type to be a *tuple* assignable to `string[]`; I want to prevent a non-tuple like `Array<"a" | "b">`.  It's not really *necessary* to prevent this, since the output type would just be wider than you like, but I wanted to forestall an objection about someone manually specifying something weird.  You can use similar tricks to prevent other specific things.

---

Let's see how it works.  This still behaves how you want:

```
const values1 = getValues(store, 'a', 'b');
/*const values1: {
    a: string;
    b: string;
} */
```

If you manually specify a type parameter, it needs to be a tuple:

```
const values2 = getValues<["a", "b"]>(store, 'a', 'b');
/* const values2: {
    a: string;
    b: string;
} */
```

If you specify the wrong tuple, you get an error:

```
const values3 = getValues<["a", "b", "c"]>(store, 'a', 'b'); // error!
// -----------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Expected 4 arguments, but got 3.
```

If you specify or pass-in a union for one of the tuple elements, you get the union of object types out:

```
const aOrB = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";
const values4 = getValues(store, aOrB); 
/* const values4: {
    a: string;
} | {
    b: string;
} */
```

which can become a fun union of lots of things:

```
const cOrD = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "c" : "d";
const values5 = getValues(store, aOrB, cOrD); 
/* const values5: {
    a: string;
    c: string;
} | {
    a: string;
    d: string;
} | {
    b: string;
    c: string;
} | {
    b: string;
    d: string;
} */
```

---

So that all works!  There are probably plenty of edge cases I haven't considered, though... and even if it works it's clunky and complicated.  So again, I'd probably just recommend documenting your original function so that callers are aware of the limitations of the compiler.  But it's neat to see how close you can get to the "correct" output type!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysD2AnaBeKAlCBjJATAPAM7CICWAdgOYA0UxZVAfANwBQrokUAquafHwBeETDkQEA0rQBqjKGglQIAD2ARyuQlAAKieJESgJEEFAD8UAN5QA2tqgUoEgLoAuKNKgBfKO-IQANwhENk5oAFFlMABDDXwAFTk0eKVVdU0HcgAzYJ5zK1tFRwBrE3gsnjceGxdvXyh-IJCOcGhefiERbDx4gFcwABsIYxBCfEUVNQ0tXX1goxMbZxkkqEiYuNYobYKbAElMqFKQcqcqgApld3aBUmFRPHH95Y9GAEp5OQD4UlxvG3IvQAtgAjYLOVJTTRbHbnS7uCg5RAYD4oL4-XAfCzoeqNYKsFjsLK9chYYAdKCUCDAaTRAa9CBjCZpaZQc6A0G5SbpLQSGwAciGVGAAAt+RCLDZ6BRKBD3NKqEs3oxzjDtsQkBB3HBNbQAHQG46Edw2A16lysN7XPi3e7dcR9QbDExM2gKyhySxqqA4cjEKABOkMrRoSw+aJaWIgZhQAD0sYa8GAUAA7kgyBA-tEQfBesnSEDBnRojlQFARcEIOwdkcXXqskhwtEsCK4WBUZ7vTXff7A-TUHQEMgbGBnGwazXSBVzn2GR8vRPFwGg4yRxC0LOIOOlz4IANCNAF0ua5vCGv5FB+eR4Mv+-zt4uvN6vG82N7kMBeohyLfg2wn+w8Y8IQ0RUnGUDIAAjr0pDIEC6jAMaNbsD2yYasg2pDgOYYxkBEaEMC0CkPmWhZKQAxDH8KbESKUDRIgILEYg9GmKe7CsKhv6MgAjBeVI0iuhDnOhEC0Py0T8mJIL8q+rCxgAVJxp7ce4R7bNE8okDKD5QCCmkMJQ-5QPJsYoQIvaCQATHx1K0v2Yw2AARNEjm0I5IKOc4KoiWJElSTJbAKT65nJqelmqd6GmDgZOl6dF2msD4JlmX6oWCQAzDZAn2fgTkuW5HluVgnneVhvmSZe0mvnGCbBHoiAAIRyQmAC0bXtR1LVyAAfr1fX9QNg1DcNQ3NWsUTYGofwACx0YglCEeQiG0CCeaUkmUDpXqKX+tEADyiAAEIXgAstEop6sxGjwEC5wfPgUAAAx6gArPkzmOfU7mOWwSmCbNaD8XZwbCWVdEHYdslBX99nTRFNZRe6RkAD5WN6cVI4lxmmRxIU+gdAAip3nSKl2xLgN13VAD3PW9FiOcVX24D9uOpVxhBvYDtmCaDurg0dtBYIT1VyfJwVs6eL3wzsiNaVQOlYPpCU+Kjal0Ur8vergGuGVjqvozrCuG3raM1hjcu6zW2vxZrSU41AQA)

Comment: This is a very impressive and much more detailed answer than what I dared to hope for. I will probably follow your suggestion to stick with my original code, though I am glad that I asked and got this much information (which will take me quite some time to understand). Thanks a lot.